# How to use StringFormat to round a bound double value

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, string-formatting

I cannot get my DataBinding to cut off the decimal digits of my sliders double value and add a % sign. I want that my view only displays "89%" even if the sliders value is 89.1234. Is it possible to use stringFormat in WPF DataBinding to realize that behavior?

```
<Label Content="{Binding ElementName=Slider, Path=Value}"/>
```

Thank you very much in advance for any help.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You cannot use the Binding's `StringFormat` if you are also using a `Label` because the `Label` has a property called `ContentStringFormat` that overrides the binding's `StringFormat`

Either use the Label's `ContentStringFormat` property

```
<Label Content="{Binding ElementName=Slider, Path=Value}" 
       ContentStringFormat="{}{0:N0}%" />
```

Or switch to using a `TextBlock`

```
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=Slider, Path=Value, StringFormat={}{0:N0}%}" />
```

Comment: @H.B. Me neither... I only use them when I want selection capabilities for a limited number of items. If I want selection capabilities for a large number of text items I will actually use a custom class which is a `TextBlock` that changes to a borderless `TextBox` on `MouseOver` instead of a `Label`, because it reduces the number of elements that get drawn on the screen, which improves performance.